# Is there a way to trigger .opened() in angular-ui modal?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to find out how to trigger `.opened()` for my modal. What I want to happen is, after all the data is loaded in my modal, I would like to `.opened()` to be triggered. I am aware that `opened()` is triggered when the modal is already opened, is there a way to change that, like maybe only trigger it after I have initialized the values in my controller?

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
    });

    modalInstance.opened.finally(function() {
           doSomething();
    });
```

asdas

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  init();

  function init() {
     // do initializations here....
     // then resolve the opened() function... but how?
  }

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using ` modalInstance.opened.then(function((){...})`

Comment: @Serginho, the `opened`promise gets called when the template and variables have been resolved, not based on any particular action within the modal's controller.

Comment: yep, I would like to control when opened is called. Though, I could probably use `.dismiss` or `.close`, but it's not ideal because I don't want to close the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass object with 'onOpen' function:

```
  $scope.ctrl = {
    onOpen: function() {
      console.log('open!');
    }
  };

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        ctrl: function () {
          return $scope.ctrl;
        }
      }
    });
```

and then:

```
function init() {
  ctrl.onOpen();
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wxwkV1cjT1gO8xGZDVgm?p=preview

Comment: I think this is the answer, without modifying ui-bootstrap there will be no way to change the behavior of the `opened` method.  The passed in function achieves the same functionality and is quite simple.

Comment: thank you. I will try this out. I was looking for a way to pass data from the modal back to my controller without closing the modal.